# If a series converges for all rearrangements, do these rearrangements all converge to the same value?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

As part of a bigger proof I assumed in my work that this is true, but until now I couldn't find a compelling argument for it. I thought about assuming that this does not hold and therefore one could construct a divergent series, but I did not make substantial progress on that. Do you have any hints how I could proof that?

Comment: If *all* rearrangements are convergent then the series converges *absolutely,* so ...

Comment: That is what I am trying to show actually. My further proof basically assumes that the is not absolutely convergent. This would violate the Riemann series theorem, because all rearrangements converge to one value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\sum a_n$ converges, but $\sum |a_n|<$ doesn't, then the subseries of all positive (or all negative) terms is divergent and we can obtain a divergent rearrangement e.g. by interspersing negative summands "very sparsely". In other words, your given confition implies that the series converges absolutely. This again implies that all rearrangements converge to the same limit.

Comment: "Sparsely" could mean something like: For each negative element $a^-$ group positive elements so that their sum is bigger than $a^-$, right?

Comment: The value of the subsum is probably irrelevant as long as it does not form a convergent series. (I chose 1 now)

Comment: But thanks a lot! That was actually a shorter way to my real goal of showing the relationship between an absolute convergent series and it's rearrangements.^^